# how to logout facebook in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

How to Logout action performed in my website who are login via facebook 
my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function Main(){
        parent::__construct();
        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
        $CI = & get_instance();
$CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
$config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
$this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

    }

    function index(){
        // Try to get the user's id on Facebook
        $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();

        // If user is not yet authenticated, the id will be zero
        if($userId == 0){
            // Generate a login url
            $data['url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email'));
            $this->load->view('main_index', $data);
        } else {
            // Get user's data and print it
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            print_r($user);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

my  view

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Click here to login</a>
```

config/facebook.php

```
<?php
$config['appId']  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';//i have my id like 1411574xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';// i have my id like 2f3917995d2024xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

my library :Facebook.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require_once "base_facebook.php";

/**
 * Extends the BaseFacebook class with the intent of using
 * PHP sessions to store user ids and access tokens.
 */
class Facebook extends BaseFacebook
{
  const FBSS_COOKIE_NAME = 'fbss';

  // We can set this to a high number because the main session
  // expiration will trump this.
  const FBSS_COOKIE_EXPIRE = 31556926; // 1 year

  // Stores the shared session ID if one is set.
  protected $sharedSessionID;

  /**
   * Identical to the parent constructor, except that
   * we start a PHP session to store the user ID and
   * access token if during the course of execution
   * we discover them.
   *
   * @param Array $config the application configuration. Additionally
   * accepts "sharedSession" as a boolean to turn on a secondary
   * cookie for environments with a shared session (that is, your app
   * shares the domain with other apps).
   * @see BaseFacebook::__construct in facebook.php
   */
  public function __construct($config) {
    if (!session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
    if (!empty($config['sharedSession'])) {
      $this->initSharedSession();
    }
  }

  protected static $kSupportedKeys =
    array('state', 'code', 'access_token', 'user_id');

  protected function initSharedSession() {
    $cookie_name = $this->getSharedSessionCookieName();
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
      $data = $this->parseSignedRequest($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
      if ($data && !empty($data['domain']) &&
          self::isAllowedDomain($this->getHttpHost(), $data['domain'])) {
        // good case
        $this->sharedSessionID = $data['id'];
        return;
      }
      // ignoring potentially unreachable data
    }
    // evil/corrupt/missing case
    $base_domain = $this->getBaseDomain();
    $this->sharedSessionID = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $cookie_value = $this->makeSignedRequest(
      array(
        'domain' => $base_domain,
        'id' => $this->sharedSessionID,
      )
    );
    $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
    if (!headers_sent()) {
      $expire = time() + self::FBSS_COOKIE_EXPIRE;
      setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, '/', '.'.$base_domain);
    } else {
      // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
      self::errorLog(
        'Shared session ID cookie could not be set! You must ensure you '.
        'create the Facebook instance before headers have been sent. This '.
        'will cause authentication issues after the first request.'
      );
      // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
  }

  /**
   * Provides the implementations of the inherited abstract
   * methods.  The implementation uses PHP sessions to maintain
   * a store for authorization codes, user ids, CSRF states, and
   * access tokens.
   */
  protected function setPersistentData($key, $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to setPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    $_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;
  }

  protected function getPersistentData($key, $default = false) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to getPersistentData.');
      return $default;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]) ?
      $_SESSION[$session_var_name] : $default;
  }

  protected function clearPersistentData($key) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to clearPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    unset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]);
  }

  protected function clearAllPersistentData() {
    foreach (self::$kSupportedKeys as $key) {
      $this->clearPersistentData($key);
    }
    if ($this->sharedSessionID) {
      $this->deleteSharedSessionCookie();
    }
  }

  protected function deleteSharedSessionCookie() {
    $cookie_name = $this->getSharedSessionCookieName();
    unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
    $base_domain = $this->getBaseDomain();
    setcookie($cookie_name, '', 1, '/', '.'.$base_domain);
  }

  protected function getSharedSessionCookieName() {
    return self::FBSS_COOKIE_NAME . '_' . $this->getAppId();
  }

  protected function constructSessionVariableName($key) {
    $parts = array('fb', $this->getAppId(), $key);
    if ($this->sharedSessionID) {
      array_unshift($parts, $this->sharedSessionID);
    }
    return implode('_', $parts);
  }
}
```

my library base_facebook.php

my library  fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

now i am log in successfully but unable to logout how to log out implement in this please

Answer (score 0):

Try this link

$params = array( 'next' => 'https://www.myapp.com/after_logout' );

$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.

use this in view and access the facebook